# Need help finding a book/graphic novel series

Tags: story-identification, magic, witches

The book was about 2 siblings- a red haired girl and a blonde boy. They were both magic/witches. I think the girl was a fire user and the boy was an ice user? Basically in the story, witches/magic users are feared by the government, so any caught using them are automatically arrested, sent to "witch houses"/jail, and then killed. At one point in one of the books there was a scene where their entire family/line of unrelated witches was lined up for a public hanging. I can't remember much but basically the two escape and try to overthrow the government in what was *at least* a 3 part book series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?